# Place as few knights as possible on an 8 by 8 chess board so that every square is controlled by at least one knight.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, chessboard

Squares containing knights should be controlled as well.  I think you need at least 3 knights to cover a corner, i.e. have the outside squares covered by knights, so that would be at least 12 knights to cover the board.  16 knights is the best I have done so far.  I need to find the minimum and prove it's the minimum.

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_chess_problem#:~:text=Domination%20problems,-Another%20kind%20of&text=In%20these%20problems%20it%20is,%2D%208%2C%20knights%20%2D%2012.

Comment: I am trying to prove the "attack all squares" version.  So 14 knights is the minimum and I need to prove it.

Comment: The attack all squares problem is easily found on the Internet too, and has been solved long ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For each cell $(i,j)$, let $N_{i,j}$ be the set of neighbors (a knight's move away) of $(i,j)$, and let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether a knight is placed on $(i,j)$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{(k,\ell)\in N_{i,j}} x_{k,\ell} &\ge 1 &&\text{for all $i,j$} &(\alpha_{i,j} \ge 0)\\
x_{i,j} &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i,j$} &(\beta_{i,j} \ge 0)\\
\end{align}
Here, the dual variables are indicated in parentheses.
The linked page shows a solution that yields an upper bound of $14$.  The following optimal dual values prove the lower bound:
$$\alpha=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1 \\ 
1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 
1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 
1 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\beta=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As you can check, multiplying each constraint by its corresponding dual value and adding them all up will yield $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j} \ge 14$.